# What's the difference between degree and grade?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Maybe I am wrong but sometimes I am pretty sure to have seen something like
"I graduated in my university with a degree of 105".
Shouldn't "grade" be used in this case?

I though that "degree" was used to identify a specific course, for example "master degree".

Comment: In this context, a *grade* is a score, which can be compared to other scores, in order to determine how well you performed a particular task. When I was in school, typical tasks which were scored were tests and quizzes, papers and projects (e.g. for the science fair), and completion of a class or course (e.g. I got a "B" in Math this semester, or an "A" in Organic Chemistry, etc). A *degree* by contrast, is awarded upon successful completion of an entire University curriculum, as in a Bachelor's degree, a Masters (e.g. in Fine Arts), or doctorate (PhD).

Comment: Unless the graduation ceremony was in a particularly hot environment, or you had a fever. On the other side of that coin, I've not heard an American usage of the 100 point scale at graduation. Usually what's referenced is a grade point average, if at all. The 100 point scale is usually translated to grade letters anyway. This seems awkward.

Comment: @choster given what you've posted, who'd be using 100 point scales at graduation in times since the 70s? (Although I'm probably more interested in the OP's source and the source's date.)

Comment: @user2370114 Who says the OP is American? The 100-point scale is still quite common elsewhere in the world. In fact, a web search turns up many websites to convert such a score into a 4.0-scale GPA.

Comment: @choster You ask a fair question. That puts an interesting twist on how to talk about English language (especially this site). If the terms aren't used in (for example) US English or UK English, but some other English, will any particular answer be correct *enough* if "Other English speaking countries" use a term in a specific way that is not how it may be in the US or UK? Admittedly, this is getting off topic for the question posted, though. The title asks one question; the body asks a different question. Neither should have a regional resolution for the purposes of this site, right?

Comment: @user2370114 You are new to the site, and I was trying to be friendly. The intent of my comment was to point out that your comment about American usage is not only irrelevant, but historically inaccurate, and is one I would edit or delete. *It should go without saying* that on the Internet, anyone can be from anywhere. This site is not restricted to US or UK English, either, though that is where the preponderance of answerers come from.

Comment: @choster Also, I didn't assert that the OP is American. My query was about the source of OP's quote and date it might apply. The conversion from 100 point scale to GPA is known. It doesn't necessarily tell us who uses 100 point scale at graduation. On topic, it's still a grade or score, it's not a degree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16195/discussion-between-user2370114-and-choster).

Answer (score 3):

Degree is not an appropriate word choice here, nor is it one I have encountered as a native English speaker. The 105 in your example sentence should be a grade or a score (most likely an average or cumulative grade).

You can earn a degree of a certain type (a bachelor's degree, a degree in physics) but not of certain score.

In some situations (a low-grade job is like a job of low degree), degree is a synonym for a grade, but this is not one of them.

Looking at [definitions of degree in the Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/degree), any acceptable usage of degree with a number is limited to usage as a unit (100 degrees) or a specific term (second-degree murder, first-degree burn).